# Tab spaced data to padded columns

Tags: tabs, alignment, spaces

Looking for a column formatting script, I have a feeling this could be a one line awk.  Ideally, a small shell script is all I am after.

The data is tab separated, each cell in each row is of variable length, and of course, may have spaces in it.

So we have something like this

```
dasj    dhsahdwe    dhasdhajks  ewqhehwq    dsajkdhas
e dward das dsaw    das daswf
fjdk    ewf jken    dsajkw  dskdw
hklt    ewq vn1 daskcn  daskw
```

Should end up something like this:

```
dasj       dhsahdwe   dhasdhajks ewqhehwq   dsajkdhas 
e dward    das        dsaw       das        daswf     
fjdk       ewf        jken       dsajkw     dskdw     
hklt       ewq        vn1        daskcn     daskw
```

Ideally, being able to adjust the amount of hard spaced between each one.  Even better if it looks on a column by column basis, so leading short cells do not all get the same right padding.

Not ideal:

```
1       dhsahdwe   dhasdhajks ewqhehwq   dsajkdhas 
2       das        dsaw       das        daswf     
3       ewf        jken       dsajkw     dskdw     
4       ewq        vn1        daskcn     daskw
```

Ideal:

```
1  dhsahdwe  dhasdhajks  ewqhehwq  dsajkdhas 
2  das       dsaw        das       daswf     
3  ewf       jken        dsajkw    dskdw     
4  ewq       vn1         daskcn    daskw
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a BSD-derived OS (including Mac OS X), column(1) and its -t option might do what you want:

```
% column -t coltest                                                               
dasj  dhsahdwe  dhasdhajks  ewqhehwq  dsajkdhas
e     dward     das         dsaw      das        daswf
fjdk  ewf       jken        dsajkw    dskdw
hklt  ewq       vn1         daskcn    daskw
```

Comment: might want to also add -s options to limit the column delimiters. By default space and tab might delimit columns.

I Almost went with the gawk answer til I saw this one. thanks for providing a simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

In un-obsfucated Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my (@data, @length);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split(/\t/);
    foreach my $i (0 .. $#line) {
        my $n = length($line[$i]);
        $length[$i] = $n if (!defined($length[$i]) || $n > $length[$i]);
    }
    push(@data, [ @line ]);
}

$length[$#length] = 0; # no need to pad the last column
my $fmt = join("  ", map { "%-${_}s" } @length) . "\n";
foreach my $ref (@data) {
    printf $fmt, @$ref;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Tested with "gawk".

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t";
    # max: Column width
    # fpl: Fields per line
    # data: Fields in every line
}
 { # Note the blank before this brace
    fpl[FNR] = NF;
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        data[FNR, i] = $i;
        if (length($i) > max[i]) {
            max[i] = length($i);
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (l=1; l<=length(fpl); l++) {
        for (i=1; i<=fpl[l]; i++) {
            fmt = "%-" max[i] "s";
            if (i > 1) {
                printf " "; # This goes between columns
            }
            printf fmt, data[l, i];
        }
        printf "\n";
    }
}
```